# Prove $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$ is convergent when $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x}{(e^xf(x))'}dx$ is convergent

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $f(x)$ is positive monotone increasing function over $[0,\infty)$, and it has derivative. Prove: if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x}{(e^xf(x))'}dx$ is convergent, then
> $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$ is convergent.

My work:
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x}{(e^xf(x))'}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)+f'(x)}\Bbb{dx}$, but since $f'(x)>0$  I do not know what to do next.

Comment: @red_rose Maybe the condition that $f(0) \ne 0$ should be impose.

Comment: Not sure why there is both a bookmark and a downvote (both not mine, I voted up).  The first integral has no issue at 0 because $f$ is assumed positive. If there is any issue with convergence at all, it must be at infinity. If $f'\ge f$, then the result follows. So one possible line of attack could be to consider the region $\{ x : f'(x) < f(x) \}$ and see if some useful bounds can be proven

Comment: There appears to be an inconsistency between the title of the question and the body. Which direction of the implication is of interest?

Comment: Isn't "if x then y" equivalent to "y when x?" But yes, it'd probably be clearer if the title were rephrased (because the body's if-then statement is more conventional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I suspect that there might be an easier solution available, this is my best idea so far:

---

For each $n \in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, let

$$E_n = \{ x \in [n, n+1] : f'(x) \geq 2f(n+1) \}.$$

Also, let $|E_n|$ denotes the measure of $E_n$.

- Assume that $|E_n| > \frac{1}{2}$. Then
  $$f(n+1) \geq f(n) + \int_{E_n} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x > f(n) + f(n+1),$$
  a contradiction.
- The previous step shows that $|E_n| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Then
  \begin{align*}
  \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+f'(x)}
  &\geq \int_{[n,n+1]\setminus E_n} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+f'(x)} \\
  &\geq \int_{[n,n+1]\setminus E_n} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{3f(n+1)} \\
  &\geq \frac{1}{6f(n+1)},
  \end{align*}
  and so,
  $$\frac{1}{f(n+1)} \leq 6 \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+f'(x)}. $$

Therefore

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)}
\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}
\leq \frac{1}{f(0)} + 6 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+f'(x)}.
$$

Now by the assumption, the right-hand side is finite, and therefore $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)}$ converges.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I guess the shifting might have caused a slight confusion. Either way, I simplified my proof a bit and I hope this is much transparent than the older one.

Comment: That is a nice tweak  to  the integral test convergence!